# [Linux cfs scheduler ]why task running time is much small than sched_min_granularity_ns

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduled-tasks, schedule

The `sched_min_granularity_ns` is 1.5ms:

```
ubuntu@VM-4-7-ubuntu:/$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/sched_min_granularity_ns
1500000

sysctl_sched
  .sysctl_sched_latency                    : 12.000000
  .sysctl_sched_min_granularity            : 1.500000
```

But when I trace the scheduler events, the task is only run 1.5us, and then schedule out. Why the task's run time is so small compared to `sysctl_sched_min_granularity`?

[image]

Comment: Does it ever do I/O?

Comment: maybe， i use sysbench to test, it's may problem , it's created thread  not process